# ExtJS remote filtering - determine filter data type on the server side

Tags: extjs, extjs-mvc, gridpanel, extjs5

I'm implementing remote filtering on gridpanels in my ExtJS MVC application. Client sends serialized filter to the server side correctly but unfortunately on server side i'm not able to determine which type of data is the filter. I'm currently receiving json data in this format:

```
[{\"operator\":\"gt\",\"value\":1412114400000,\"property\":\"ExpirationDate\"}]
```

I would like to have one more field reporting the data type in this json, for example:

```
[{\"operator\":\"gt\",\"value\":1412114400000,\"property\":\"ExpirationDate\",\"dataType\":\"date\""}]
```

This is the model

```
Ext.define('CGovAuthWeb.model.UtenteModel', {

extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [
    { name: 'ID' },
    { name: 'Userid '},
    { name: 'UserName'},
    { name: 'Password'},
    { name: 'Email'},
    { name: 'Comment'},
    { name: 'IsApproved'},
    { name: 'IsLockedOut'},
    { name: 'IsOnline'},
    { name: 'ExpirationDate'},
    { name: 'LastActivityDate' },
    { name: 'CreationDate'},
    { name: 'LastLockoutDate'},
    { name: 'LastLoginDate'},
    { name: 'LastPasswordChangedDate' },
    { name: 'BloccatoChanged', defaultValue : true}
],

idProperty: 'ID'

});
```

The store looks like this:

```
Ext.define('CGovAuthWeb.store.UtenteStore', {

extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

autoSync: false,
remoteFilter: true,
remoteSort: true,

requires: ['CGovAuthWeb.model.UtenteModel'],
model: 'CGovAuthWeb.model.UtenteModel',

storeId: 'Utente',
pageSize: 15,

proxy: {
    type: 'rest',
    url: 'api/utente',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        rootProperty: 'Results',
        messageProperty: 'Message',
        totalProperty: 'Total',
        idProperty: 'ID',
        successProperty: 'Success'
    },

    writer: {
        type: 'json',
        writeAllFields: true
    }
}


});
```

The following code fragment is the column in the gridpanel:

```
        {
            flex: 2,
            header: 'Scadenza',
            dataIndex: 'ExpirationDate',
            editor: {
                xtype: 'datefield',
                allowBlank: true,
                format: 'd/m/Y',
            },
            filter: {
                type: 'date'
            }
        },
```

Any suggestion is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining these two overrides in the overrides folder is a good solution to the problem.

```
Ext.define('Ext.override.grid.filters.filter.Base', {
override: 'Ext.grid.filters.filter.Base',
createFilter: function(config, key) {
    var me = this,
        filter = me.callParent(arguments),
        type = me.getInitialConfig('type');
    filter.type = type;
    return filter;
}
});
Ext.define('Ext.override.util.Filter', {
override: 'Ext.util.Filter',
getState: function() {
    var me = this,
        state = this.callParent(arguments);
    if (me.type) {
        state.type = me.type;
    }
    return state;
}
});
```

An application refresh with sencha cmd is needed after this modification. In the application root folder run the command:

```
sencha app refresh
```

Many Thanks to the Sencha Support Team!